# How to handle Ruby on Rails error: "Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rubygems

Running a Ruby on Rails (RoR) app or Ruby code which uses the ActiveRecord framework, you get the error message:

> Please install the postgresql adapter:
>   `gem install
>   activerecord-postgresql-adapter`

Trying to run:

```
gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter
```

also fails, leaving you at a loss.

Comment: You could read [the following post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/137366) to get an idea.

Comment: My attempts at following that post are included in my original answer, as they did not work for me.

Answer (score 128):

The problem is not what anyone wrote.
The problem is that the name of the postgresql database adapter is "postgresql", not "postgres", though the name of the GEM is "pg".

The definition in the database.yml file should include

```
  adapter: postgresql
```

Comment: Is this something that could be fixed fairly easily?  I mean so that the names are corrected and error messages appropriate?

Comment: Please install the postgres adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgres-adapter`

Comment: what if i am just using ruby and not ror ? I can't find any datbase.yml file

Comment: @boulder_ruby - ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-postgres-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the answer I got from Heroku and it worked for me (after trying different pg gems, adapters, and everything else on the 10 other posts about this)

1) add the line: gem 'pg' to your Gemfile.

2) Run the command bundle install to install the gem into your bundle.

3) Stage the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock changes: git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock

4) Commit the changes: git commit -m "Install the pg gem"

5) Redeploy to heroku: git push heroku master

Answer (score 9):

This means you don’t have the new ‘pg’ postgresql library installed. This is easily fixed with a bit of:

```
sudo gem install pg
```

I (Dov) found other solutions on the web which described setting GEM_HOME and adding ~/.gem/ruby/vers/bin to your PATH, but they didn't work. This solution above was provided by
Mark Mansour on his blog State of Flux at:
http://stateofflux.com/2008/7/13/activerecord-postgresql-adapter-in-rails-2-1/

Comment: This one did not work for me ... still looking for a solution.

Comment: I don't recommend installing gems with sudo.  Better yet, use Bundler.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more deeply hidden condition that will also cause this error.

If you have a local environment variable **DATABASE_URL=postgres://mehmehmeh** set, then some gem (I suspect Heroku) causes the app to think that Postgres is required even if it's nowhere in your configs. Kill that env variable and you should be fine.

Comment: This was my problem. Tricky!

Comment: Really useful for me as well. I was not using pstgresql anywhere in my project but an old DATABASE_URL environment variable was there hiding and causing this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was facing this issue till last 3 days. And finally found an answer from you @chad. Thanks again.

Comment: I was getting a bizaar error about the Active Record 'http' Adapter that was caused by this environment variable being in my `.env`. Glad I finally found this post!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

On debian(squeeze):

```
aptitude install libdbd-pg-ruby
```

Answer (score 2):

Check database.yml environment db is correct. If it is postgresql, you might need to change it to refer to mysql2 or whatever db your using for your given environment.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev

then...

gem install pg

Worked for me!

Comment: What if we want to use 1.9.2?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little roundup of the current state of Ruby + PostgreSQL database drivers on [railsonpostgresql.com](http://railsonpostgresql.com/2009/09/04/rails-postgresql-and-database-drivers); I think `sudo gem install pg` is probably the one you want.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the difference between different drivers. Information not as easy to find as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

While trying out different search results, I installed a bunch. What finally got my environment to stop complaining with this message: "Please install the postgresql adapter: gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter" was:

- I removed all gems relating to the adapter such as:
  sudo gem uninstall activerecord-jdbc-adapter;
  sudo gem uninstall activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter;
  sudo gem uninstall activerecord-postgresql-adapter;
  sudo gem uninstall jdbc-postgres;
- I also removed references to adapter as followed inside my Gemfile:
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
- Leave only pg (0.15.1) installed (to check for existence of pg, do "gem list")

Then running "rake db:create" works. So, I guess pg is the latest and works. However, it does not get used when other broken adapter gems are around.