# Activerecord-PostgreSQL Adapter Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle Ruby on Rails error: “Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem)

When running "rake db:migrate", i receive the following error:

Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle)

1. Postgres 8.4.4 installed using the pre-built image file.
2. Then ran `sudo gem install pg` to install pg-0.9.0
3. Config/database.yml:
   `development:`
   `adapter: postgresql`

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that I used the prepackaged install from PostgreSQL.  I reinstalled postgresql using macports and it worked great.

Good instructions in this blog:

http://eddorre.com/posts/installing-ruby-on-rails-postgresql-mysql-on-snow-leopard