# Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`

Tags: ruby, postgresql, redmine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle Ruby on Rails error: “Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem)

I'm trying to get Redmine working with postgres.

In my logs I keep seeing.

```
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`
```

After googling everyone said you needed to do gem install pg.  But when I do gem list

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.8, 2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.8, 2.3.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
passenger (2.2.15)
pg (0.9.0)
postgres (0.7.9.2008.01.28)
postgres-pr (0.6.3)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
```

You can clearly see that pg is already installed.  Has anyone else found this issue or fixed it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

make sure your db-adapter in database.yml is set to "postgresql". If still you have the same problem, then try using the pure-ruby adapter:

```
gem install postgres-pr
```

(make sure you uninstall the pg gem before... to avoid conflicts)

If it works, then it's a problem with the postgres gem. Anyway, for development purposes, using the pure-ruby gem is usually ok.

Answer (score 5):

I had more luck with the ruby-pg gem

> > gem install ruby-pg

I tried a number of the other gems 'postgres', 'pg', 'postgres-pr' with no luck
My environment was Ubuntu 10.4, ruby enterprise 1.8.7

ruby-pg resolved the above issue for me

Answer (score 3):

for debian squeeze it is:

```
aptitude install libdbd-pg-ruby
```

Comment: works for wheezy too

Answer (score 2):

Similar (almost identical) errors can arise in Rails 3.0.4 with Postgres and pg, when you mistype the adapter name in your database.yml, for instance "postrgesql" instead of "postgresql":

Please install the postrgesql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postrgesql-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/postrgesql_adapter)

Answer (score 1):

```
gem install postgres-pr
```

worked for me on Windows 7 with Rails 2.3.4

Comment: Just be aware that it is a poor performer. You probably shouldn't use it for production.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with postgre sql gem, but I've solved similar error before by adding this into *config/preinitializer.rb*.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'

ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/[username]/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
Gem.clear_paths
```

Note: you'll have to use your own gem locations. Usually you can find them by running `gem environment`.

You may also find some answers here useful:
[How to handle Ruby on Rails error: "Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem-i)

Comment: Now I get /opt/redmine/apps/redmine/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76:in `establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.so) (RuntimeError)

Comment: It's not related to ruby anymore, something's wrong with your native postgre library. In particular, have you downloaded correct version (32/64 bit)?   Also, there seems to be a lot of related content in google for "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64"

Comment: Postgres or PostgreSQL - not postgre