# Postgres Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been pulling out my hair trying to get this to work. Any experience or info would be very appreciated.

When trying to recompile Rails 3.1 assets locally (before I push to Heroku) I get the error:

> rake assets:precompile --trace
>   ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
>   ** Execute assets:precompile
>   rake aborted!
>   Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter' 
>   (no such file to load --active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter)

Then when I go to install the gem I get an error:

> Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository

Any help greatly appreciated, this is causing me gray hairs.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this answer may help:

[How to handle Ruby on Rails error: "Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem)

It looks like the gem is called "pg", so: `gem install pg`

You may also want to check your database.yml file, as the first answer in the linked post suggests.

Comment: I saw that too, and when I run with the suggested changes, I get
rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Permission denied
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Tasks: TOP => environment

Comment: postgresql isn't my strong point, so hopefully someone will chime in at this point.  Did you check that /var/pgsql_socket.s.PGSQL.5432 exists?  Have your tried connecting to it outside of rails?  Is it chowned by the same user that is running rake?