# Ruby on Rails postgres adapter error when trying to run the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems

I have installed all the gems that I saw listed in [How to handle Ruby on Rails error: "Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem) - none of them work. It doesn't matter if I have postgres or postgresql in my databases.yml file.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong (I also installed the driver mentioned in the error as well. I keep getting that error.

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `gem': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

I am trying to run "rails server webrick -p 80 -e production"

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: imentor
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: 
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

---

My problem was that I didn't actually know where to edit the gemfile ( (looked at the wrong gem file originally)

adding "gem 'pg'" to the Gemfile fixed it. Thanks to 'mu is too short'

Comment: I added what i have in /usr/bin/gem (not 100% sure if this is the right one - i also added 'pg' to it)

Comment: You should have a file called `Gemfile` in the root directory of your Rails app.

Comment: Awesome! my ignorance of gemfiles was to blame, it works now that I added "gem 'pg'" to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't actually know where to edit the gemfile (looked at the wrong gem file originally)

adding "gem 'pg'" to the Gemfile fixed it.
Thanks to 'mu is too short'

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu I just do

```
apt-get install libpgsql-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem like this a few weeks back. I think you should try adding this code to the boot.rb file at first.

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

You should also try addding this to the grmfile and run a bundle install right after

```
gem 'pg'
```

If it helps also this is a sample of my database.yml file. Hope it works!

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dezirus
  username: postgres
  password:
```

Comment: wouldn't it complain about not being able to parse or something related to yaml? This is also a brand new installation of everything, so there wouldn't be any problems with legacy code (which I think is where the yaml problems may come in)